# Access xampp from VMWARE to Public IP

Tags: xampp, vmware

Is it possible to access 127.0.0.1:8080 publicly i have a project application that is running on VM, What should I do?

**Diagram:**

```
VMachine( where xampp is installed) IP <-> Global(external) IP (167.1.174.21:8080)
```

I don't have any option left what should i do i'm really new to this. **#respect**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible but there are multiple steps to the configuration and the details for each steps differ depending on the hardware/software used. In general though it can be accomplished like this:

#### VMware config

1. Configure the VM with a [bridged network](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_bridged_ws.html)
2. Configure the guest OS to either have a ***dhcp reservation*** or *static ip*.

#### Router config

1. Add a ***dhcp reservation*** for the VM (if using DHCP)
2. Add a port forwarding rule pointing to the VM's IP address

#### XAMPP config

1. Make sure the XAMPP server is listening on all interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

The key point is to make the Virtual Machine to have bridged connection.

You can do it by looking at [this one](http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-10/index.jsp#com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-476EEC7C-4DBA-481B-A772-52CFC572E2A7.html).

After that do a Port Forwarding to the virtual machine like it a real machine on your LAN.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the vm has a configured network and is therefor able to communicate with your LAN (using Bridged networks in the VM configuration is a good way to go) and the internet, it is possible to make it accessible to the external web/internet.

Therefor you would most likely need to define a port-redirect/port forwarding on your router, that all incoming packets on the external IP (167.1.174.21) on port 8080 gets forwarded to the local ip of your vm and the related xampp session.

A possible problem at that point might be changing IP addresses of the VM based on a possible DHCP configuration. Either use a fixed IP on the VM or configure some mac-based rule for fixed IP or increase the lease time of the dhcp-server (your router to unlimited)

That's the theory, **but please** think twice before you do so. Running a webserver which is available in the wild is not recommended if you are not used to IT security. And even if you decide to do so, using xampp sounds wrong to me ears. xampp is designed for local development & testing purposes, not for productive use.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1 :** Apart from above solution, in your local network where xampp is installed, make your local ip as static one, like "192.168.1.125" from router settings->Address reservation option.

Once you reserve address

**Step 2 :** Open your router->port forwarding->set port & ip to forward.

**Step 3 :** Now you check your public ip, and bingo now you can go to your public ip from vmware or from any other network.

Comment: which ip to be forwarded? guest or host. be more clear